# How can I monitor the haxe cpp garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection, monitoring, performance-testing, haxe

I would like to ensure the garbage collector is not overused in haxe (cpp target).

I already have pools of large objects and frequently reused objects that I managed to efficiently recycle. But there are still some slowdowns. I'm sure I can limit some of the inconsistent slowdowns and skipped frames by reducing garbage collection.

How can I collect data about the gc? I would like to see the list of classes collected, the number of times they are collected and the number of objects registered in the GC.

Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`untyped __cpp__('code');` will let you execute arbitrary cpp code(passed as it is). Using this construction you can access any inner mechanisms, including garbage collector, so if youlook in gc implementatio, you can do anything you want I guess. You also can directly patch gc part of haxe after it was compiled to cpp.

Answer (score 1):

For Haxe 3.1, use cpp.vm.ExecutionTrace.traceFunctions(); , traceLines, traceOff